# Is it possible to automatically lock direction of two finger scroll on touchpad

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

There is one feature that is available on Windows and which I would really love to discover on Linux. It works the following way.

Suppose I have an area which I can scroll both vertically and horizontally. Whenever I start scrolling it with two fingers on the touch pad, Windows detects the main scrolling direction (vertical or horizontal) and preserves it until I stop scrolling no matter how far I move my fingers in the direction perpendicular to the main detected direction.

For instance, if I start scrolling down, but also slightly to the right (just by a mistake), Windows detects that my intention is to scroll vertically and filters out my mistake by scrolling the area only vertically. Once I release my fingers from the touch pad and start scrolling say to the right, but also slightly up (again just by a mistake), Windows detects my intention and preserves the horizontal direction, not paying any attention to vertical movement of my fingers.

My current workaround is a keyboard shortcut for a script that toggles `synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll`, but this is not as convenient as what I have on Windows. Other `synclient` options do not seem to help either.

Is it possible (and how) to achieve on Linux the same scrolling behavior as I have on Windows?

In case that matters: Asus U36SD, Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: Very interesting question, I'd love to discover such a feature too.

Comment: @ByteCommander see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1064183/266507). Also, I'm voting to close this question as duplicate of that one.

Comment: Hmm, weird, there's no linked question in the list of candidates to close this one as duplicate. Oh well, I dunno ¯\_(ツ)_/¯