# Problem with two-finger scrolling on the touchpad

Tags: mouse, touchpad, synaptics

When I scroll vertically, it scrolls horizontally in parallel. It is impossible to slide two fingers down in the table, so that there is no horizontal scrolling. This was not the case before. I want to make sure that when I scroll down in the table, the screen does not move a little to the right / left. That is, I want both horizontal and vertical scrolling to be available, but when calling one, the second one does not activate so quickly. I hope I have explained the essence of my problem)

is it possible to block both scrolling at the same time? (with two fingers, horizontal and vertical)

`synclient -l` command response:

```
Parameter settings:
LeftEdge                = 77
RightEdge               = 1863
TopEdge                 = 70
BottomEdge              = 1227
FingerLow               = 25
FingerHigh              = 30
MaxTapTime              = 180
MaxTapMove              = 102
MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
SingleTapTimeout        = 180
ClickTime               = 100
EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 10
EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
VertScrollDelta         = -46
HorizScrollDelta        = -40
VertEdgeScroll          = 0
HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
CornerCoasting          = 0
VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
MinSpeed                = 1
MaxSpeed                = 1.75
AccelFactor             = 0.0857265
TouchpadOff             = 0
LockedDrags             = 0
LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
RTCornerButton          = 2
RBCornerButton          = 3
LTCornerButton          = 0
LBCornerButton          = 0
TapButton1              = 1
TapButton2              = 3
TapButton3              = 0
ClickFinger1            = 1
ClickFinger2            = 3
ClickFinger3            = 0
CircularScrolling       = 0
CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
CircScrollTrigger       = 0
CircularPad             = 0
PalmDetect              = 1
PalmMinWidth            = 10
PalmMinZ                = 200
CoastingSpeed           = 20
CoastingFriction        = 50
PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
ResolutionDetect        = 1
GrabEventDevice         = 0
TapAndDragGesture       = 1
AreaLeftEdge            = 0
AreaRightEdge           = 0
AreaTopEdge             = 0
AreaBottomEdge          = 0
HorizHysteresis         = 11
VertHysteresis          = 11
ClickPad                = 1
RightButtonAreaLeft     = 970
RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
RightButtonAreaTop      = 1063
RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

Comment: Please explain -This was not the case before- When was this and what has changed?

Comment: @David Previously, when vertically scrolling with two fingers of the touchpad, the horizontal scrolling was not immediately invoked.

Comment: Sorry do not get it you just repeated the same thing the question said. Good luck.

Comment: @David is it possible to block both scrolling at the same time? (with two fingers, horizontal and vertical)

Comment: I think what you want to ask is; how to restrict to one axis scrolling at a time. That means, scrolling vertically does not scroll horizontally, and vice versa. For this you can add thresholds, There is a similar question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/871618/how-can-i-make-my-touchpad-scroll-either-vertically-or-horizontally-but-not-bot But it does not have any definite answers to it. Also here are how you can modify behaviour of devices in an older answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/577212/43493